# Carrierwave on Rails with ActiveDirectory adds tmp folder in store_dir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am trying to use carrierwave and it is uploading the file fine, but I wanted my mp4 file to be in the public/uploads directory. It adds it there, but put it into a tmp/some-weird-id folder. I want just the mp4 file in public/uploads. Is this possible? If so, how? I have tried editing the cache_dir, but it still adds that weird id folder.

Here is the code so far:

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads" # This saves to Rails_Root/public/uploads
  end

  def move_to_cache
    true
  end

  def move_to_store
    true
  end
```

Here is the controller

```
 def create
    @file = params["video"][:file].original_filename
    @video = Video.new({ :upload_file_name => @file, :user_id => current_user.id})
    @video.file = params["video"][:file]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @video.save!
        format.json { render json: {files: [@video.id]}, status: :created }
      end
    end
 end
```

Comment: Your `create` method doesn't look right. Either you work with the uploader directly `uploader.store!(my_file)` or you mount it to a model `u.avatar = params[:file]`. You shouldn't have to work with the filenames directly. See https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instruct Carrierwave to *move* the file to your storage directory, rather than copy it by overriding the `move_to_cache` and `move_to_store` methods in your uploader.

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def move_to_cache
    true
  end

  def move_to_store
    true
  end
end
```

You can read about this in the [Carrierwave documentation about large files](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#large-files)

Comment: What folder is empty? Can you post your uploader configuration please?

Comment: I should say it adds the file but instead of it being:

`public/uploads/filename.mp4`

It is

`public/uploads/tmp/1469257810-5440-0001-0417/filename.mp4`

Comment: Wow I am super dumb. Fixed the question above with working code. Will mark this as the answer. THANKS!!!